# Append text based on g's id to a selection of gs: Cannot read property 'attr' of undefined

Tags: html, d3.js, attr

I have several g on my page each with a different id. 
I would like to append to each of these g a text that displays this id.

This is my code:

```
    d3.selectAll("g")
        .append('text')
        .attr('x', 60)
        .attr('y', 90)
        .text(function(d) {return d.attr("id")})
        .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
        .attr("font-size", "20px")
        .attr("fill", "blue");
```

It returns an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attr' of undefined
    at SVGTextElement.<anonymous>
```

Comment: `d` refers to the datum, not to the DOM element. It should be: `.text(function(){return d3.select(this.parentNode).attr("id")})`

Comment: please add this as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In D3, the famous first argument refers to the *datum* bound to the element (and, because of that, the respective parameter is normally named `d`).

You don't want the datum. You want to get the `<g>` element which is the parent of the texts. Therefore, use:

```
.text(function() {
    return d3.select(this.parentNode).attr("id")
});
```

Here is a demo:

```js
d3.selectAll("g")
  .append('text')
  .attr('x', 60)
  .attr('y', (_, i) => 20 + i * 20)
  .text(function() {
    return d3.select(this.parentNode).attr("id")
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <g id="foo"></g>
  <g id="bar"></g>
  <g id="baz"></g>
</svg>
```